# Which variables should I use to substitute?

Tags: integration

Calculate the integral
$$\iint_D \cos \left(y^2 \over x\right)\sin \left(x^2 \over y\right)\,dx\,dy$$
where $D$ is the set
$$D = \left\{(x,y) ~\Bigg|~ {\pi\over4} \le {y^2\over x} \le {\pi\over2},~~ {\pi\over6}\le {x^2\over y}\le {\pi\over3} \right\}$$

---

I have to solve the integration changing to another system of variables. I tried to substitute $x=u$ and $\sqrt y = v$, also i tried that $\frac yx =A$ but I didn't manage to solve the question.

Comment: What if $\displaystyle u={y^2\over x}$ and $\displaystyle  v={x^2\over y}$?